# How do I delete / rename files on Bq M10 file manager using attached keyboard/mouse?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, filemanager, bq, m10

To delete or rename a file on the Bq M10 tablet with no attached device, I touch and hold. But, how is this done with an attached keyboard / mouse? Right click does not seem to do anything and left click opens the file.

Answer (score 0):

In File Manager, go to the folder you want and then you will see a list of files. Hold down a finger (or a stylus !) on the file you want to delete for about a second. A menu appears with one of the options as 'Delete'.

Comment: It seems the OP knows how to do it using the touch-screen, (s)he wants to know how to do it  using the mouse or keyboard. Probably you misunderstood the question.